# How to flip a pattern of bits in binary representation?

Tags: python-3.x, bit-manipulation

I have a String like this **BGGBG**. Now i have to flip all **BG** to **GB**.In this string there is two **BG**'s.Now if i want to represent it as Binary(taking B=0 and G=1) then it would be **01101**. So from this want to flip **01** to **10**. Is this possible to do? if yes How can it be done in **Python**?

**FYI**: This is **not** just **flipping bits**(0 to 1 and vice versa).Rather it has to do with **flipping a pattern**(like **01** in this case).

I know i could have just used str.replace() like this:

```
string=string.replace("BG","GB") # will replace all BG to GB
```

Actually this can be a decent approach to solve this problem here at codeforces. https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/266/B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your binary string is in `bg`: this sets `mask` to  1 only in the positions where `bg` has a `01`.  The 1s are doubled in `flip`, and XORd with the original to get the result:

```
>>> bg = 0b00011011
>>> mask = bg & (~bg>>1)
>>> flip = mask|mask<<1
>>> result = bg ^ flip
>>> bin(result)
'0b00101101'
```

Comment: Note that this will give a wrong answer if the first char is 'G'=1, because leading zeros trigger the detectiion.  You'll need to filter those out in the string conversion, or when creating the mask.

Answer (score 1):

I’m not suggesting that this is the best, most sustainable, or even an acceptable way to do it, but it certainly was fun writing this. I hope it brings you closer to solving what you’re trying to solve:

```py
import re

# I’m assuming that the string is "((BG)*(GB)*)*"
# any other characters will make this fail
input = 'BGBGBGGBGBGB'
output = ''

for two in re.findall('..', input):
    output += int.to_bytes(int.from_bytes(two.encode(), 'big') ^ 1285, 2, 'big').decode('ascii')

print(input)
print(output)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot@Dodekeract. I have tried out your code but seems like it sets off some characters.

Comment: Can you be more precise @AminAhmed?